# spark-xml: How to create a SparkSQL table from the atrributes of an XML file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an XML file that looks like follows:

```
<report>
     <instance name="XYZ" number ="1">
          <key value="ABC"/>
          <key value="ABCD"/>
     </instance>
     <instance name="PQR" number ="2">
          <key value="ABCDE"/>
          <key value="ABCDF"/>
     </instance>
</report>
```

I want to create a SparkSQL table of the following fashion

```
name  number  value
XYZ    1      ABC
XYZ    1      ABCD
PQR    2      ABCDE
PQR    2      ABCDF
```

Is this technically possible?

I am using pySpark, and this is what I have done till now:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag", "report").load("//path//to//file.xml")
df.registerTempTable("XMLtable");
```

I got the schema as:

```
root
 |-- instance: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- @name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- @number: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- @value: string (nullable = true)
```

I performed the following queries:

```
sqlContext.sql("select * from XMLtable").show();

+-------------+
|     INSTANCE|
+-------------+
|[[null,XYZ...|
+-------------+

This query correctly points me to the right data. 

sqlContext.sql("select instance[1].key[1]['@value'] as value from XMLtable").show();

+--------+
|  value |
+--------+
|(1)ABCDF|
+--------+
```

So as far as I understand, the table is not correctly loaded as expected. How will I load the table with attributes as opposed to the general way of loading values.

Can anybody point me towards the right direction? I have already checked without attribute values, and that works pretty well. What I need is to create a table like described above with the attributes values populated, which will inturn help in writing queries for the parsed XML data. I also plan to convert this into pandas dataframe later to do more statistical analysis of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. First, specify `instance` instead of `report` for `rowTag` option during loading xml and add specify custom value for `valueTag` (to avoid conflicts with `value` attribute), for example:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag", "instance") \
        .option("valueTag", "some_value").load("data.xml")
```

Then you can easily get dataframe to requested format using:

```
>>> df.withColumn('values', explode('key')).select(
       col('_name').alias('name'), 
       col('_number').alias('number'), 
       col('values._value').alias('value')
    ).show()
+----+------+-----+
|name|number|value|
+----+------+-----+
| XYZ|     1|  ABC|
| XYZ|     1| ABCD|
| PQR|     2|ABCDE|
| PQR|     2|ABCDF|
+----+------+-----+
```

Finally, register this dataframe as temp table and it will behave like you expected.

Comment: @Mariuz Cool. Thanks a lot! I had to make an edit (use '@' instead of '_') to make this work and also had to load the python sql library explicitly. Just one more thing here: In my data.xml file, I have various other tags that embeds <instance> within it. But I am interested to parse only the <instance> tags within <report>. So what change will I have to do in the "rowTag" option?

Comment: You need to specify `report` as rowTag and explode dataframe one time more to get `instance` content.